# How to connect MySQL db using new XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql

Old connection method `mysql_connect` maybe deprecated from PHP7 so what is the best way to connect and query in mysql using XAMPP or how I implement PDO in my bellow script.

```
<?php
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("search", $con);

    $query = mysql_query("select * from ajax_example where name LIKE '%{$key}%'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $array[] = $row['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Mysqli_* manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and PDO_* manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database connection using `mysqli_*` :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

For further `mysqli_*` statement syntax refer: [`Mysqli_*` Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Database connection using `PDO_*` :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

For further `PDO_*` statement syntax refer [`PDO_*` Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
    $conn = new Connection(); 
    $query = "select * from ajax_example where name LIKE '%{$key}%'";
    $res = $conn->execute_query($query)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($res)) 
    {    
        $result['data'] = $res;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: what about the connection ?

Comment: you have to create connection file.

Comment: lets not encourage SQL injection