# Linux Ubuntu Xampp MsSql setting

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, xampp

Can someone help me how to setting connection for mssql in xampp on ubuntu platform?

So I can use:

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37652503/1763484

Comment: but how to setting sql server connection in xampp? is that necessary?